# Template correction in XSLT

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-1.0

```
<To>
    <Id>SERVICE</Id>
    <Role>Commuter</Role>
</To>
<BPD>
    <OrgNo>234</OrgNo>      
</BPD>
<BON>123</BON>
```

I have this Input XML in which I want to check whether `//To/Id` contains SERVICE or not.
If it contains SERVICE then a element should be added after `<BPD>` naming `<BON>SERVICE</BON>`.
Also I want to check if my Input XML already contains `<BON>` element then its value should be
replaced by SERVICE which is in `<Id>` element.

I have created a template for this ->

```
<xsl:template match="BPD">
 <xsl:choose>
   <xsl:when test="not(BON) and normalize-space(/To[Role='Commuter']/Id)='SERVICE'">
     <BON>
    <xsl:text>SERVICE</xsl:text>
     </BON>
   </xsl:when>          
   <xsl:when test="normalize-space(BON) and normalize-space(/To[Role='Commuter']/Id)='SERVICE'">
      <BON>
    <xsl:text>SERVICE</xsl:text>
      </BON>
    </xsl:when>
 </xsl:choose>
</xsl:template>
```

This template is checking whether  exists or not. If it doesn't exist then it creates `<BON>`
element and adds 'SERVICE' as value to it.
And if  exists then it creates one more element  which is not required.
I need to correct my second when situation.

Comment: Are you trying to replace the existing `<BON>` or add to it?

Comment: Both are the cases. 1) IF <BON> doesn't exist then add to it and value should be SERVICE. 2) IF <BON> exists then its value should be replaced by SERVICE.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're just replacing the existing `<BON>` if it exists, you should only need this:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:output indent="yes"/>
  <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

  <xsl:template match="node()|@*" name="ident">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="BPD[../To[Role='Commuter']/Id='SERVICE']">
    <xsl:call-template name="ident"/>
    <BON>SERVICE</BON>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="BON[../To[Role='Commuter']/Id='SERVICE']"/>  

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

With either this input:

```
<doc>
  <To>
    <Id>SERVICE</Id>
    <Role>Commuter</Role>
  </To>
  <BPD>
    <OrgNo>234</OrgNo>      
  </BPD>
  <BON>123</BON>  
</doc>
```

or this input (no `<BON>`)

```
<doc>
  <To>
    <Id>SERVICE</Id>
    <Role>Commuter</Role>
  </To>
  <BPD>
    <OrgNo>234</OrgNo>      
  </BPD>
</doc>
```

it will produce this output:

```
<doc>
   <To>
      <Id>SERVICE</Id>
      <Role>Commuter</Role>
   </To>
   <BPD>
      <OrgNo>234</OrgNo>
   </BPD>
   <BON>SERVICE</BON>
</doc>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think what you are saying is that is that if you have a **To** element with a **id** of 'SERVICE' and a **Role** of 'Commuter' then you want to ensure there is a following **BON** element with a value of 'SERVICE' (replacing any existing one if it already exists).

This can be done without using an **xsl:choose** but two separate matching templates. Firstly you can match the case where you have a **BON** element and the preceding elements are for 'Commuter' and 'SERVICE'.

```
<xsl:template match="BON[preceding-sibling::To[Role='Commuter'][normalize-space(Id)='SERVICE']]">
```

Then you can have a template that matches the **BPD** element where there is no **BON** element at all.

Here is the full XSLT

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
   <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>

   <xsl:template match="BON[preceding-sibling::To[Role='Commuter'][normalize-space(Id)='SERVICE']]" name="bon">
      <BON>SERVICE</BON>
   </xsl:template>   

   <xsl:template match="BPD[preceding-sibling::To[Role='Commuter'][normalize-space(Id)='SERVICE']][not(following-sibling::BON)]">
      <xsl:call-template name="identity" />
      <xsl:call-template name="bon" />
   </xsl:template>

   <xsl:template match="@*|node()" name="identity">
      <xsl:copy>
         <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
      </xsl:copy>
   </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Do note the use of named templates, to avoid duplicate coding of the **BON** element.

When applied to the following XML

```
<Root>
   <To>
      <Id>SERVICE</Id>
      <Role>Commuter</Role>
   </To>
   <BPD>
      <OrgNo>234</OrgNo>
   </BPD>
   <BON>123</BON>
</Root>
```

The following is output

```
<Root>
   <To>
      <Id>SERVICE</Id>
      <Role>Commuter</Role>
    </To>
    <BPD>
       <OrgNo>234</OrgNo>
    </BPD>
    <BON>SERVICE</BON>
</Root>
```

If you changed the input XML to the following, then it would also yield the same output in this case

```
<Root>
   <To>
      <Id>SERVICE</Id>
      <Role>Commuter</Role>
   </To>
   <BPD>
      <OrgNo>234</OrgNo>
   </BPD>
</Root>
```